# How to get one property and output from a child job?

Tags: windows, powershell, properties, jobs

I have a child job in a file test.ps1:

```
param($unit)
$p = $unit

Start-Job -Name $unit -ScriptBlock {
    param($p)

    "Hallo $p"
    New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Not_found = "agurk"
    }
} -ArgumentList $p
```

When I do:

```
PS> .\test 2
PS> $a=Get-Job|Receive-Job |Select-Object -Property Not_found
```

I unfortunately get

```
PS> $a.count
2
```

Why 2 and not 1?

And I have to do

```
PS> $a[1].Not_found
agurk
```

in order to get the value.

I want to create a child job which produces some output, and one property and only one for the caller to investigate. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a count of 2 because your job returns the string `"Hallo 2"` and your custom object `@{Not_found="agurk"}`. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return):

> In Windows PowerShell®, the results of each statement are returned as output, even without a statement that contains the Return keyword.

The `Select-Object` doesn't skip over or remove that string, instead it creates a new custom object with an empty property `Not_found`, so you end up with a result like this:

```
[
  { 'Not_found': '' },
  { 'Not_found': 'agurk' }
]
```

If you don't want the string output to be captured, change this line:

```
"Hallo $p"
```

into this:

```
Write-Host "Hallo $p"
```

Or don't create undesired output in the first place.

If the additional output is desired and you need to be able to redirect it separately from the returned object you can't use `Write-Host`, though, since that cmdlet writes directly to the host console (meaning its output cannot be captured or redirected). Instead you need to write to a [different stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/), e.g. the verbose stream:

```
Write-Verbose "Hallo $p"
```

Note that you need PowerShell v3 or newer to be able to redirect streams other than the Success and Error streams.

Comment: Ok, but the output is desired, since the caller might direct it to an output file. But the caller also want to detect the value of the property. Does that really means, that he has to iterate through all the output to find the property object? It sounds cumbersome

Comment: If you want to be able to redirect output separately from the returned object you need to write it to a [different stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/), e.g. the verbose stream (`Write-Verbose`). Note that you need PowerShell v3 or newer to be able to redirect streams other than the Success and Error streams.

Answer (score 0):

The count of two comes from the fact the job returns two lines of output, `"Hallo $p"` and the object.

Because you're doing an unconditional select, it seems Powershell is returning objects whether or not the property exists.

You could change your query to check whether or not the property is populated by using a `Where-Object`:

```
$a = Get-Job | Receive-Job | Where-Object { $_.Not_Found -match ".+" }
```

Then access with `$a.Not_Found`

Alternatively, directly accessing the property from your result also seems to only return non-empty values:

```
$a = $(Get-Job | Receive-Job | Select-Object -Property Not_Found).Not_Found
```